# How to scroll the UICollectionview from particular cell

Tags: ios, scroll, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a collection view. I need to scroll only cell4, cell5, cell 6 so on. First two cells are remain same. Is is possible using only `UICollectionview`. How to achieve this.

FYI: the height of the cell is more than the screen height.

[image: sample collection view]

Answer (score 0):

One of options would be to subclass `UICollectionViewLayout` and update frames in attributes of first three cells every time when scroll offset changes. So the cells would look static.

Comment: Does it help or you need more details?